# Class visibility (private) inside __construct parameters - is this a valid php code?

Tags: php, php-8

I'm looking at some one else's code that I do not understand. This is example of class:

```
class ImageService
{
   public function __construct(
       private ImageTransformer $imageTransformer,
       private PostService $postService
   ) {

   }

   // other methods here
}
```

IDE is showing errors under _construct due to "private" inside params.
I know that in PHP 8 there are union types, but I cannot find any info about using "private" or "public" not inside class but inside constructor, and what this supposed to do. I thought that this is typo, and it supposed to be inside class, but multiple classes are created like this. Is this a valid code or someone does not know what is he doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is new in PHP 8.0.0 and is called [Constructor Promotion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor.promotion).

> As of PHP 8.0.0, constructor parameters may also be promoted to correspond to an object property. It is very common for constructor parameters to be assigned to a property in the constructor but otherwise not operated upon. Constructor promotion provides a short-hand for that use case.

If you [execute that code](https://3v4l.org/ttEgp) you will see.  You should check to see if your IDE has been updated to support PHP 8.0.0.